# a program that finds a function on a javascript webpage and run that in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

So I'm trying to write a program that finds a java script function in a webpage (the page is written in java script) and a loop that runs the function until the user pushes a button.

I think the best way to write this is an add-on so it can have its necessary accesses to browser.

It must consist of two parts, first a block finder, something like easy filter in AdBlockPlus or block element in AdBlock+ which finds a java script function; and then a function that repeatedly runs the java script function that it found on the first step with a 500ms delay until the user tell it to stop, perhaps with a specific key.

I know the general but I haven’t got a clue how to start. And I only know how to program in c++.
I’m not in a rush, I’ve got like 20 days but that’s not enough for trial and error so I had to ask you guys these questions.

My questions are:

Is it even possible to write the code with this algorithm?

Which browser should I choose for writing this add-on?

What I need to learn for writing this add-on?

Comment: how about including that .js file and using the function accordingly ?eg. <script src='myscript.js'></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing Chrome extensions, you really need to know javascript since all the moving parts will be written in javascript. You would also have to know html and css.

For a good starting point, you should checkout the info tab of [google-chrome-extensions tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome-extension/info).

There you find a good amount of information to get you started.

For Firefox Extensions, you can either create xul based extensions, or with the new addon-sdk. You can see a chart with a comparison [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html).

In both of them you have to know javascript as well.

About what browser you use, i can't really choose it for you, but i hope i gave you enough information to choose for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you want to create a function that is executed every 500ms, you can use this HTML:

```
<BODY onload="time()"> ...
```

and this JavaScript:

```
timer = null;

function time() {
    check();
    window.setTimeout("check();", 500);
}

function check() {
    //do something
}
```

To stop the loop, use

```
<A ... onclick="window.clearTimeout(timer); return false"> ... </A>
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not asking for code. I think I'm just start with learning how to write addon for chrome. what I still don't know is that should I learn javascript too or learning html for writing addon is enough?!

Comment: @user2100555 To stop the loop you will ahve to fix your code to: `timer = window.setTimeout(check, 500);` and when you need to clear it you will ahve to write `clearTimeout(timer);` A timeout runs only one time. while `setInterval` will repeat after each nms

Comment: @NULL Yes, stupid me! Error fixed.  I've never seen `setInterval` before...

Comment: @ProfMax You can check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: @Arwen If you want to do this, you will need to learn some programming language because HTML is only any use for displaying your page.  For a Chrome add-on, JavaScript would be best.

Comment: @ProfMax I've already started learning it.thanks again.